# How to set expiration time for hmset in node redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, chat, chatbot, node-redis

I used to do `client.setex(key, 900, value)` for storing single key-value.
But, I want to store an object with expiration time.
I come up with function `hmset`, but I don't know how to make expiration time.
I want to use it to store the context and the text of current chat in conversation.
Please help

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To expire a Hash (or any other Redis key for that matter), call the [`EXPIRE`](https://redis.io/commands/expire) command. In your case:

```
client.hmset(key, ...
client.expire(key, 9000)
```

Comment: The thing is those are 2 commands, means the entire operation is not atomic. If, for whatever reason, client.expire() will not be processed, you'll end up with a record that would never expire. It would be great would Redis have a single command for both setting a hash and defining its expiration time all at once.

Comment: Yes, but you can use a `MULTI/EXEC` block or a Lua script to ensure atomicity in lieu of a dedicated command.

Comment: @StasKorzovsky I need to set expiry for my key set in hash via hmset. Can you help me how we can do it ? Above method is showing me TTL for key as -1.

Answer (score 4):

Since, `hmset` is deprecated ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61826300/10204932)), you can use `hset` with `expire` using `pipeline`.

```
pipe = client.pipeline()
pipe.hset(key, mapping=your_object).expire(duration_in_sec).execute()

# for example:
pipe.hset(key, mapping={'a': 1, 'b': 2}).expire(900).execute()
```

> **Note**: [Pipeline does not ensure atomicity](https://rafaeleyng.github.io/redis-pipelining-transactions-and-lua-scripts).

Comment: Thanks, worth to mention that to ensure atomicity you can use `multi()` instead of `pipeline()` (As stated in the article you linked)

Answer (score -3):

A good way to ensure that expiration is set after the key is to wrap the process in an ES6 async function:

```
async function (keyString, token, ttl) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            redisClient.hmset("auth", keyString, token, function(error,result) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    redisClient.expire(keyString, ttl)
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't help you to ensure atomicity, which is discussed above.