# How to switch from hmset() to hset() in Redis?

Tags: python, redis

I get the deprication warning, that Redis.hmset() is deprecated. Use Redis.hset() instead.

However hset() takes a third parameter and I can't figure out what `name` is supposed to be.

```
info = {'users': 10, "timestamp": datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}
r.hmset("myKey", info)
```

The above works, but this requires a first parameter called name.

```
r.hset(name, "myKey", info)
```

Comparing the [hset](https://redis.io/commands/hset) vs [hmset](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) in docs isn't clear to me.

Comment: You can use `hset("myKey", mapping=info)`.

Comment: Sorry doesn't seem to accept it.

Comment: It appears the `mapping` kwarg was added in 3.5.0 (Apr 29, 2020). If your version is older, you will need to do as @Ersoy suggests.

Comment: @hmm it may be related to library's min-redis version. HSET with multiple field/value pairs is available since Redis v4.0.0.

Comment: Yes, sorry, updating the lib to `redis-3.5.2` makes the warning in PyCharm go away.  Now I don't know which answer to accept. Both are correct. I think for clarity I go with Ersoy. Thanks both.

Comment: i will upvote @hmm then for more updated one :) - you are welcome Houman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may execute multiple `hset` for each `field/value` pair in `hmset`.

```
r.hset('myKey', 'users', 10)
r.hset('myKey', 'timestamp', datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
r.hset('myKey', 'yet-another-field', 'yet-another-value')
```

- first parameter is the key name
- second parameter is the field name
- third parameter is the value of the field.

Comment: This works but is not a good switch from hset to hmset using the same intended action - which is one call to set multiple fields - so this should not be the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you must specify within `hset()` that you are giving it the mapping. In your case:

```
r.hset("myKey", mapping=info)
```

instead of

```
r.hset("myKey", info)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer - the goal of the question is to set multiple fields in one call - not how to set each field individually.

Answer (score 11):

`hmset(name, mapping)`: given a hash name (`"myKey"`) and a dictionary (`info`) set all key/value pairs.

`hset(name, key=None, value=None, mapping=None)`: given a hash name (`"myKey"`) a key and a value, set the key/value. Alternatively, given a dictionary (`mapping=info`) set all key/value pairs in `mapping`.

Source: https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

If this does not work, perhaps you need to update the library?

Comment: This is technically right but is less clear than the answer by David Cano.

Answer (score 4):

I was using **Redis.hmset()** as following:

```
redis.hmset('myKey', info)
```

If you use **Redis.hset()** the following you will not get warning.

```
redis.hset('myKey', key=None, value=None, mapping=info)
```

With this usage, we will skip the single key & value adding step and  `redis.hset()` will set all of the `key` and `value` mappings in `info` to `myKey`.